# Disappearing plugins

Tags: plugins, wp-cli

I've had a problem with disappearing plugins lately. Several of my plugins are installed and are working, but you can't see them in the admin plugin interface, only WP-CLI. The plugins are "Custom Post Type UI", "Disable Application Passwords", and "Simple History". I've checked for security problems and can't find any. I have reinstalled the missing plugins from the zip source to make sure I've got clean versions. I also I tried disabling all the plugins to see if they would reappear in the list, and they do not. I have also re-installed Wordfence from the zip archive and done a scan...nothing out of place. I have tried all this under WP 6.1.1 and 6.2, no difference.

I'm kind of at a loss for what to try next. Ideas?

If it matters, this is for a Kinsta site. The Cloudflare CDN and Edge caching they use are off.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out... I had Admin Menu Editor Pro installed, and I forgot it has the ability to hide plugins, which I had apparently done at some point and forgot about. D'Oh!